# Powershell how to list the values in a column under its property?

Tags: powershell, shell, object, scripting

I`d like to change the output of an object so all data can be shown.

```
$filepath = "C:\Users\vansteenkistea\Desktop\scriptExerciseProcessesWindows.csv"

$data = import-csv $filepath 

$processes = get-process| Select-Object Path

$known = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$malicious = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

#Creating the arrays
$malArray = @()
$knownArray = @()
$unknownArray= @()

#fill up arrays with data

foreach ($line in $data)
{
   $known.add($line.known)
   $malicious.add($line.malicious)
}

foreach ($process in $processes)
{
    foreach ($mal in $malicious) 
    {
        if ([bool]($process -like '*' + $mal +'*' )) 
        {
            Write-Host "$($process.path) is mall"
            $malArray+= $process.Path
        }
    }

    foreach ($know in $known)
    {
        if ([bool]($process -like '*' + $know +'*' ))
        {
            Write-Host "$($process.path) is known"
            $knownArray += $process.Path
        }
        elseif ($process.Path.Length -ne 0) 
        {
            Write-Host "$($process.path) is unknown"
            $unknownArray+= $process.Path
        }
    }
}

$yourData = @(
  @{known=$knownArray;Unknwon=$unknownArray;Malicious=$malArray}| % { New-Object object | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $_ -PassThru }
)

$yourData
```

My output:

[image: My Output]

Desired output:

Something that looks like this

[image: Desired output]

I've tried multiple things like format table, put the data inside an Object instead of an array, etc..

Someone who knows how I can list the values in a column under its property ?

Comment: The best solution is likely to create 1 object per process, with a separate "Status" property that tells whether it's Malicious/Known/Unknown - please post the actual code (as text, not screenshots!)

Comment: Ok thanks for answering, ill try that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `for` loop to iterate through the lists?

```
$filepath = "C:\Users\vansteenkistea\Desktop\scriptExerciseProcessesWindows.csv"

$data = import-csv $filepath 

$processes = get-process| Select-Object Path

$known = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$malicious = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

#Creating the arrays
$malArray = @()
$knownArray = @()
$unknownArray= @()

#fill up arrays with data

foreach ($line in $data)
{
   $known.add($line.known)
   $malicious.add($line.malicious)
}

foreach ($process in $processes)
{
    foreach ($mal in $malicious) 
    {
        if ([bool]($process -like '*' + $mal +'*' )) 
        {
            Write-Host "$($process.path) is mall"
            $malArray+= $process.Path
        }
    }

    foreach ($know in $known)
    {
        if ([bool]($process -like '*' + $know +'*' ))
        {
            Write-Host "$($process.path) is known"
            $knownArray += $process.Path
        }
        elseif ($process.Path.Length -ne 0) 
        {
            Write-Host "$($process.path) is unknown"
            $unknownArray+= $process.Path
        }
    }
}

    for ($i=0; $i -lt ($knownArray.Count + $unknownArray.Count + $malArray.Count); $i++){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Known     = $knownArray[$i]
            UnKnown   = $unknownArray[$i]
            Malicious = $malArray[$i] }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or do something like this:

```
$filepath  = "C:\Users\vansteenkistea\Desktop\scriptExerciseProcessesWindows.csv"
$data      = Import-Csv $filepath

# create two strings, with non-empty fields are combined with the regex 'OR' pipe symbol
$regexKnown     = ($data.known -ne '' | Select-Object -Unique | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
$regexMalicious = ($data.malicious -ne ''| Select-Object -Unique | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

$processes = (Get-Process).Path

$result = foreach($process in $processes) {
    $known = $malicious = $false
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($process)) {
        $unknown = $true
    }
    elseif ($process -match $regexMalicious) {
        $malicious = $known = $true
        $unknown = $false
    }
    elseif ($process -match $regexKnown) {
        $known = $true
        $unknown = $false
    }

    # output an object
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Process   = $process
        Malicious = $malicious
        Known     = $known
        Unknown   = $unknown
    }
}

# output on screen (if 'Format-Table -AutoSize' doesn'n fit, replace with 'Out-GridView'
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save to Csv if you want
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\vansteenkistea\Desktop\WindowsProcesses.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output like:

```
Process                                                                                          Malicious Known Unknown
-------                                                                                          --------- ----- -------
C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe                                                                  False      True   False
C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe                                                                          False      True   False
C:\Windows\System32\oobe\UserOOBEBroker.exe                                                      False     False    True
                                                                                                 False     False    True
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.YourPhone_1.19122.89.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\YourPhone.exe   True       True   False
```